# In swift, send User’s current location to server while app is killed

Tags: ios, swift, location, voip

I am creating a **Taxi Driver** application in swift. I need to send the driver’s current location to the server by every 30 sec even app is killed. I found the solution while the app is in the foreground or background state. But I am not able to send location to server while app is killed. I **tried with VOIP push** and **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**.

1. When the app is killed and **VOIP** push receives by every 30 sec, I can get the user’s location but, I am not able to call API and send a location to the server. Can anyone have a solution for sending data to the server while the app is killed?
2. Using **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** while the app is killed I am able to send location to the server,  but it takes 5 to 10 minutes to get user’s updated location while he/she is driving. I tried physically by traveling from one location to another location so many times. Apple doc tells that location updates when user’s position changes by a significant amount, such as 500 meters. But in reality, it updates by 5km to 7km traveling. Can anyone have a solution for it?

Comment: @Yamanu, Your case seems to get the location in a continuous manner, you should try startUpdating method with accuracy property as per your need. but you need to instruct taxi driver to keep the app in background. Since they are special user they can take care their battery backup.  And your customer can have startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.

Answer (score 1):

“If your app is terminated either by a user or by the system, the system doesn’t automatically restart your app when new location updates arrive. A user must explicitly relaunch your app before the delivery of location updates resumes. The only way to have your app relaunched automatically is to use region monitoring or significant-change location service. However, when a user disables the Background App Refresh setting either globally or specifically for your app, the system doesn’t relaunch your app for any location events, including significant change or region monitoring events. Further, while Background App Refresh is off your app won’t receive significant change or region monitoring events even when it’s in the foreground.” [more...](https://medium.com/@calvinlin_96474/ios-11-continuous-background-location-update-by-swift-4-12ce3ac603e3)

Comment: Thanks, Adobels for your help. I have two apps. one is for Taxi Driver and another is for the customer. I can not use Regin monitoring, As I do not want to check that the driver is entered in any particular region or not. My motive is to check the driver's location wherever he is moving. So I need to send Driver's current location to server in every 30 sec even app is killed. so from customer application, customers can check the driver's current location at any time. I tried with significant-change. it updates the location by 5 - 7 km, how to get updates by every 500 meters as Apple says?

Answer (score 0):

App refresh is good idea but iOS allows only 35 to 40 seconds in background to wake up your app in background so you should call your functions in this period of time.. here is good example for location based background tasks [Usage](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)

and and and  apple document says if you use silent push notification. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it..refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app)

Comment: Thanks, Dhaval Raval for your help, if I use silent push notification, will it allow me to do Http request while I receive a push? Because I need to do an API call while i receive a push. I need to send a user's current location to the server while the app is killed.

Comment: Yeah you  can call API but as i told you OS allows you to calling function in time limit..after that OS may terminate or kills the app in background